# brms package in R smoother

Tags: r, bayesian, nonlinear-optimization

I have this data frame in R:

```
x =   rep(seq(-10,10,1),each=5) 
y =  rep(0,length(x) )
weights = sample( seq(1,20,1) ,length(x), replace  = TRUE)
weights = weights/sum(weights)
groups = rep( letters[1:5], times =length(x)/5  )
```

and some data that looks like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = x, y = y, color = group))+geom_point( aes(size = weights))+
  ylab("outcome")+
  xlab("predictor x1")+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0)+ geom_hline(yintercept = 0)



fit_brms = brm(y~ s(x)+(1|group), data = dat)
by_group = marginal_effects(fit_brms, conditions  = data.frame(group = dat$group) ,
                            re_formula = NULL, method = "predict")
plot(by_group, ncol = 5, points = TRUE)
```

I'd like to make a hierarchical nonlinear model so that there is a different nonlinear fit for each group.

In brms I have the code below which is doing a spline fit on the x predictor with random intercepts on group the fitted line is the same for all groups. the difference is where the lines cross the y intercept.  Is there a way to make the non-linear fit be different for each group's data points?

ON page 13 here :  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brms/vignettes/brms_multilevel.pdf

It states "As the smooth term itself cannot be modeled as varying by year in a multilevel manner,we add a basic varying intercept in an effort to account for variation between years"

So the spline will be the same for all groups it appears? The only difference in the plots is where the spline cross the y intercept. That seems very restrictive. Can this be modified to make the spline unique to each group?

Answer (score 2):

Use the formula: `y ~ s(x, by = group) + (1|group)`